# how to Horizontal panel slide in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile-website, mobile-webkit

I want to implement horizontal sliding panels in jQuery mobile. That is i'll have three or more tabs and when I press on tab the tab content should slide and revele its content. I dont want the whole page to slide, just tab content.

Is it possible? If its not yet possible with jQuery mobile, what other mobile frameworks I can use to have this functionallaty?

Newbie here! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hi Gaurav your question is still not fully clear to me, however, I have created two sample pages which you can check out. I hope it solves your problem.
I have used Jquery,Jquery Mobile, and jQuery UI libraries in the below two links.

1) Sliding Content in the Tab : http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay/x7LmV/14/

2) Sliding Content in an Div : http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay/qczsk/1/